# clear interval not clearing in if statement [javascript]

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

Created a timer, I want to be able to stop the interval once the seconds drop down to 0.

This is what I got so far

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    if (alarm?.timerOn && alarm?.seconds === 0) {
      console.log('stop?')

      clearInterval(alarmTimer)
      console.log('stop? below clear interval')
    }
  }, [alarm?.seconds])
```

The console logs appear exactly at 0 just like I want it but the clear interval doesn't do anything? I have declared the alarmTimer like this `let alarmTimer: any` outside the useEffect

How the start timer works

```js
 alarmTimer = setInterval(() => {
      if (alarm!.seconds > 0) {
        dispatch!({ type: 'DECREMENT_SECONDS' })
      }
    }, 1000)
```

So instead of clearing at 0 it carrys on and goes down to -1,-2,-3 etc

Comment: you might need to check the scope of `alarmTimer` again, that could be one of the reasons that it could be messing it up, and if you are using typescript, why use `any` as the typing?

Answer (score 0):

Decided to use Ref instead like this and it seems to have worked!

`const intervalRef = useRef(null)`

```js
intervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
if (alarm!.seconds > 0) {
        dispatch!({ type: 'DECREMENT_SECONDS' })
      }
}, 1000)
```

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (alarm?.timerOn && alarm?.seconds === 0) {
       clearInterval(intervalRef.current)
       intervalRef.current = null
    }
  }, [alarm?.seconds])
```